# Connecting to mongo docker container from host

Tags: node.js, macos, mongodb, docker

I'm running Docker on OS X with:

```
docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v ./data/db:/data/db -d mongo mongod
```

and using the ip I get from:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <cid>
```

in:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://<ip>:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
   db.close();
});
```

and I'm getting a timed out error.

I'm using the official mongo repository from Docker Hub. Is there any additional setup that I need to do in order to connect from the host?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Is the node.js code being run from a container or from the host?

If it's on the host, just use the localhost address i.e:

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
```

This will work because you published the port with `-p 27017:27017`.

If the code is running inside a container, it would be best to rewrite it to use links and referring to the mongo container by name e.g:

```
var url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017';
```

Then when you launch the container with the Node.js code, you can just do something like:

```
docker run -d --link mongo:mongo my_container
```

Docker will then add an entry to `/etc/hosts` inside the container so that the name `mongo` resolves to the IP of the mongo container.

Comment: I'm running it from the host. I get a connection refused when I change it to localhost.

Comment: Are you sure the mongo container is still running? Have a look in `docker ps`. I just tested and it crashes immediately with a journal error for me - I had to pass the `--smallfiles` argument to get it to start.

Comment: Yep, that's staying up for me. I tried putting my program inside a container and it's connecting just fine with the link syntax.

Comment: Oh, are you using the boot2docker/the Docker Toolbox? If so you need to use the IP of the VM, not localhost.

Comment: Ah, I got it! Took me a while to figure out there's a difference between the IP of the VM and the one from the container. Thank you, sir!

Comment: I work with the new Docker Beta 17 on Mac (without Boot2Docker VM stuff). Do I still have to change any IPs inside the Node-Container (connecting to the MongoDB container)?

Comment: `var url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017';` I tried it still not working

Comment: link will be depricated, please assign the containers to the name docker network.

Answer (score 9):

Another option for anyone who use docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: "mongo"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - './dockervolume/mongodb:/data/db'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

And u can connect using the url string

```
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017")
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("db connect success");
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            throw err
        });
```

Comment: amazingly useful. thankyou so much for helping me with this

Answer (score 8):

If you use a user defined network you should be able to pick it up without linking or specifying 27017

```
const MONGO_NAME_STR = "mongodb://" + "your_docker_container_name";
var db = {};

mongo_client.connect(MONGO_NAME_STR, function(err, _db){
  //some err handling
  db = _db;
});
```

Comment: really underrated answer

Comment: amazing answer combined with the fellow below

Comment: This is really amazing!! We tried all possible approaches for 2 whole days and finally stumbled across this answer. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

Using docker-compose, same can be achieved as below

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

The connection string is as below,
On Host -

```
const uri = "mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/
```

On Container -

```
const url = 'mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017'
```

Port mapping can be configured to use a custom host port [8000] like - `8000:27017`